# Expand/Collapse table row Javascript works wrongly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table

I'm using this code to expand database table row to reveal more information about the item, but it does exactly the opposite.

```
    $("td span.expand").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr.main").nextUntil("tr.main"). toggle();
});
```

When I open the table all rows that must be hidden are being shown and if I click on any main row it will hide that rows.
How to invert this?
Here's part of code I use for table (I know, it's messy):

```
    echo '<table border="1" class="tabula">
<tr class="main">
<th width="30px"><a href="?page='.$page.'&sort=nr&sort_by='.$sort_order.'">Nr.</a></th>
<th width="75px"><a href="?page='.$page.'&sort=numurs&sort_by='.$sort_order.'">Mašīnas numurs</a></th>
<th width="75px"><a href="?page='.$page.'&sort=regnr&sort_by='.$sort_order.'">Reģistrācijas numurs</a></th>
<th width="75px"><a href="?page='.$page.'&sort=modelis&sort_by='.$sort_order.'">Marka / Modelis</a></th>
<th width="75px"><a href="?page='.$page.'&sort=apzim&sort_by='.$sort_order.'">ID</a></th> 
</tr>';

    //Ieraksta datus tabulā
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
  {
  echo "<tr class='main'>";
    echo "<td width='30px'>" . $row['nr'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='75px'>" . $row['numurs'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='75px'><span class='expand'>" . $row['regnr'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['modelis'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['apzim'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr class='hidden'>";
    echo "<td>text</td>";
    echo "<td>text</td>";
    echo "<td>text</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Try using CSS in your file and include `<style> .expand { display:none; } </style>` - I use a jQuery-based toggle script, and that's what I used when I had a similar problem such as this. You may need to use `.hidden { display:none; }` instead. However, I use an `id` for mine.

Comment: Great, now it works how it must work. Thanks, Fred :)

Comment: You're welcome. Want me to make it an answer to close the question? I'm sure somebody else will come along and use my comment to do so. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- TIL about Ahoy!

Comment: What does `TIL` mean? lol @MikeB

Comment: Today I Learned or Things I Learned

Comment: Ah ok thanks for that (I too TIL - about `TIL`) ;-). Seems like the OP deleted the question. I have a Czech friend who shows me a thing or two, every once in a while. Blew me away when I first learned that. That's when my world was then complete in regards to the ever-so yummy "Chips Ahoy" lol @MikeB

Comment: If you can click the `white checkmark` till it turns `Green` next to my answer, is the way a question is considered "Closed" here on SO, in case you may not know. @zopa34 And welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CSS in your file and include the following:

```
<style>
.expand
{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

I use a jQuery-based toggle script, and that's what I used when I had a similar problem such as this.

You may need to use `.hidden { display:none; }` instead.